# bootstrap 3 navbar toggle collapse content not lining up evenly

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble with lining up the connections and sign out sections on my navbar toggle. As you can see, the last two are out of line with the others. I am using the bootstrap 3 site as a reference, but I'm sure I have something not marked right.

[image]

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Dash</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Record A Message</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="navbar-text">Connections <span class="badge">0</span></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <p class="navbar-text">Sign out as <a class="navbar-link" href="Login.aspx">User</a></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar -->
            </nav>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried a few different ways and the only solution I found without breaking the "mobile-first" approach was overriding the "navbar-text" class with a margin-left: 15px which also appears on the @media (min-width: 768px) line 4695.

```
.navbar-text {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit using your info and it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

trying removing the paragraph tags